# Result of Invoke-RestMethod returns a system.object[] after exported to csv

Tags: powershell, rest

I'm working on a project where I use Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell to get information that I'll export in CSV format. Seems simple enough, but I'm having an issue with the exported data. Most of the csv file is fine, but two columns just say "System.object[]" instead of the actual underlying data. The data itself is just an array of strings, but I want it exported as a single string separated by columns.

This is what I currently have:

'''

```
$scheduleResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $scheduleURL -Method GET -Headers $headers 
    
    if (!$Error) {
        $scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Workspace" -Value $workspaceName
        $scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Dataset" -Value $datasetName
        $scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Dataset ID" -Value $datasetID
        $scheduleResult | Export-Csv -Path $refreshSchedPath -Append -Encoding UTF8
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.ToString()` method when you select the value. Ex:
`$scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Workspace" -Value $workspaceName.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean "exported as a single string separated by ***commas***"?  If so, you just need to join the arrays into a single strings using the `-join` operator.

```
$scheduleResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $scheduleURL -Method GET -Headers $headers 
    
if (!$Error) {
    $scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Workspace' -Value ($workspaceName -join ', ')
    $scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Dataset' -Value ($datasetName -join ', ')
    $scheduleResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Dataset ID' -Value ($datasetID -join ', ')
    $scheduleResult | Export-Csv -Path $refreshSchedPath -Append -Encoding UTF8
}
```